# Python function all is not behaving as expected

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to use the `all` function in python for searching a matrix, but it is not behaving as expected. I would assume for `matrix` it would output `True` and for `matrix2` it would output `False`. What am I missing here?

```
  matrix= [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
           [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
            [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
                [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

matrix2= [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]


def isComplete(m):
    return all(item != 0 for item in m)

print isComplete(matrix)
print isComplete(matrix2)
```

Output:

```
True
True
```

Comment: The elements of a list of lists are *lists*.

Comment: And non-empty lists are fore sure != 0 .. and they are even truthy.

Comment: as @user2357112 wrote, `for item in m` iterates over rows, not over values in rows - try `for item in m: print(item)` to see what it does

Comment: I see. Is there a way I can use the all function to output True and then False for a list of lists that are all 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Change your `isComplete()`:

```
def isComplete(m):
    return all(j != 0 for item in m for j in item)
```

Before your code was checking only `list(non empty list)` that is why it was returning `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a nested loop here because the matrixes contain lists and not the actual numbers

```
return all(item != 0 for line in m for item in line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over a nested list, so you need a nested comprehension.

```
return all(item != 0 for sublist in m for item in sublist)
```